# Why would I need simplegeo?

Tags: geolocation

I'm building a simple location-based service where users find out stuff near them based on their positions. I've heard a lot about simplegeo but can't seem to figure out where exactly I'll need their service. Their website doesn't seem to help too as far as product description is concerned. Can anyone enlighten me as to how the fit in?